# Why does Microsoft.Build.Evaluation evaluate $(ProgramFiles) as "c:\program files" on 64 bit PC?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a C# project file (.csproj) containing references to *$(ProgramFiles)*.  I am using 64bit Windows 7.  When I compile this project file within Visual Studio 2010, it locates the file correctly in *c:\Program Files (X86)*.

If I try to be clever and instead use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject([project file]), in an attempt to build it in code, it evaluates *$(ProgramFiles)* incorrectly as *c:\Program Files*.

Any idea what the cause of the problem could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is a 32-bit process, and [WOW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64) will give `c:\Program Files (X86)` for 32-bit processes.

My assumption here:

> If I try to be clever and instead use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject([project file]), in an attempt to build it in code

Is that when you are doing it "in code", your code is executing a x64, so you get the normal environment value.

You can use the `ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variable from x64 if you need the path to the x86 program files directory. In MSBuild, that's `$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)`.